# How to compare data with a multiple selection in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these dates as example:

```
date1: 2013-01-01
date2: 2013-01-25
```

I need to create a procedure that will insert the product special offer in the database if `date1` is between these 2 dates.

```
create procedure CreateOfferProduct(
@codP varchar(5),
@date1 date,
@date2 date,
)
as
if(not exists(
        select * from OfferProducts
            where Products.codP = @codP 
            and @date1 <= (select date2 from OfferProducts where codP = @codP)
    )
)
begin
       insert into OfferProducts(codP, date1, date2) 
       values(@codP, @date1, @date2);   
end
```

But since

```
select date2 from Products where codP = @codP
```

returns multiple values it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you make sense for your business logic if you do "select MAX(date2)" or "MIN(date2)"?

Comment: What exactly does the `codP` column represent? Is this an identifier for a product? If so, why does it return multiple values?

Comment: The problem is more complex than this so I tried to rewrite the question as simple as possible. Essentially I was looking for a procedure that inserts a ProductOffer for that store if there isn't already an offer for that Product stored in the database (already). Sorry if my question was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the intersection of two time periods.  The following may be what you want:

```
. . .
if not exists (
    select *
    from OfferProducts op
    where op.codP = @codP and
          (op.date1 <= @date2 and
           op.date2 >= @date1)
  )
  . . .
```

The exact definition of overlap depends on whether the end points are included in the date range.

On re-reading the question, you explicitly state "if its date1 is between these 2 dates".  If so, then try:

```
if not exists (
    select *
    from OfferProducts op
    where op.codP = @codP and
          op.date1 between @date1 and @date2
  )
  . . .
```

Comment: But this doesn't work as an `IF` conditional because the OP wants to insert multiple rows, and only those that don't already exist.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I see nothing about multiple inserts in the question.

Comment: The OP said `since ... returns multiple values it doesn't work` - implying that there are multiple products that match the value of @codP, and that multiple rows should be inserted.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The `<=` doesn't work because the subquery returns multiple rows.  As I interpret the question, this has nothing to do with inserting more than one record; it is just getting the query in the `if` to work.

Comment: Maybe, but if the subquery returns multiple values, that suggests to me that multiple products are eligible for the special offer.

Comment: Essentially for the intersection of two time periods I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Mythul . . . Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to insert multiple rows that don't already exist in the destination, instead of doing this row-by-row technique where you assign values to a variable (which is slower and inflexible).

```
INSERT dbo.OfferProducts(codP, date1, date2)
  SELECT p.codP, @date, @date2
  FROM dbo.Products AS p
  WHERE codP = @codP
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.OfferProducts 
      WHERE codP = p.codP
      AND date2 >= @date1 -- this logic seems funny
  );
```

If you show sample data and desired results, including existing data that you want excluded from the insert, we might be able to formulate better logic for you.